# jQuery ajax call - Returning particular HTML elements

Tags: jquery

When making a call to jQuery `get`, how does one specify HTML elements to be returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AJAX call doesn't return DOM elements. It sends an asynchronous HTTP request to a server side script which returns a result which could be of any type HTML, XML, JSON, ....  This result is then passed to the `success` callback for processing:

```
$.get('/script', function(result) {
    // TODO: do something with the result returned by the server script
});
```

So for example if your server side script returned some HTML content and you wanted to extract a particular element you could do this:

```
$.get('/script', function(result) {
    // get an element with id="foo" from the returned result
    var foo = $(result).find('#foo');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Darin is right. However, you might be looking for the functionality provided by [`load`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (the Ajax method not the event handler).

Something like `$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');` will parse the response HTML for the element with the id `container` and insert it into the HTML of `result`.

You could maintain an invisible `div` and extract specific DOM elements out of it after load (`load)()` also accepts a callback that will be called when the load is finished).

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container,.classname', 
                   function(){
                      $('#result').html(); //this should give you the DOM that matches either .classname or #container
                  });
```